# Passing the same string argument to two diffrent method of a class at once in python

Tags: python, parsing

I would like to pass the same argument to the both method B and C at once by passing only one argument, but currently it is taking two. I beleive it is possible in python syntax and would appreciate if anyone could share his/her thought to solution on that.

```
class A:

    def B(self, scrpt = r'', projtNam =''):

    ##my code

    def C(self, scrpt = r'', projtNam =''):

    ##my code


if __name__ == '__main__':

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Change something')
parser.add_argument('-s', dest='scrpt', type=str, help='HELP')
parser.add_argument('-p', dest='projtNam', type=str, help='HELP')

args = parser.parse_args()
scrpt = args.scrpt
projtNam = args.projtNam

Ins = A()
Ins.B(scrpt, projtNam)
Ins.C(scrpt, projtNam)
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want here. Is the issue that you need to pass `scrpt` and `projtNam` twice to `A` and to `B`? Or is it that you need to pass them separately when you'd prefer to just pass `args`? Or both? Can you show a sample (even if non-functional) of what you'd like to do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for `__init__` method.

**Ex:**

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, scrpt, projtNam):
        self.scrpt = scrpt
        self.projtNam = projtNam

    def B(self):
        print(self.scrpt, self.projtNam)

    ##my code

    def C(self):
        print(self.scrpt, self.projtNam)

Ins = A("scrpt", "projtNam")
Ins.B()
Ins.C()
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a new method that calls `B` and `C`.

```
class A:

    def B(self, scrpt = r'', projtNam =''):

    ##my code

    def C(self, scrpt = r'', projtNam =''):

    ##my code

    def D(self, scrpt = r'', projtNam =''):
        self.B(scrpt, projtNam)
        self.C(scrpt, projtNam)

...

Ins = A()
Ins.D(scrpt, projtNam)
```